# How does IDataErrorInfo interface provide validation values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to fire more than one validation on the same element. I found code but I do not understand in which situation which validation fire. The xaml code is as follows:

```
<ComboBox 
            x:Name="CreditedParty"
            Style="{StaticResource FormControlStyle}"
            Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CreditedParties}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Amount, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <ContentPresenter 
            Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Content="{Binding ElementName=CreditedParty, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem}"/>
```

the code for vtewmodel.cs file is as follows:

```
   public string Error
    {
        get { return (_debitNote as IDataErrorInfo).Error; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = null;

            if (columnName == "Amount")
            {
                decimal amount;

                error = ValidateAmount(out amount);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) return error;

                _debitNote.Amount = amount;
                error = (_debitNote as IDataErrorInfo)["Amount"];
            }
            else if (columnName == "CreditedParty")
            {
                error = ValidateCreditedParty();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) return error;
                error = (_debitNote as IDataErrorInfo)["CreditedParty"];
            }
            else if (columnName == "DebitedParty")
            {
                error = ValidateDebitedParty();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) return error;
                error = (_debitNote as IDataErrorInfo)["DebitedParty"];
            }
            else
            {
                error = (_debitNote as IDataErrorInfo)[columnName];
            }

            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();

            return error;
        }
    }

    private string ValidateAmount(out decimal amount)
    {
        amount = -1;
        string error = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_amountString))
            error = Strings.JournalViewModel_Amount_Missing;
        else if (!decimal.TryParse(_amountString, out amount))
            error = Strings.JournalViewModel_Amount_NaN;

        return error;
    }

    private string ValidateCreditedParty()
    {
        string error = null;

        if (_debitNote.CreditedParty == _blankCreditedParty)
            error = Strings.JournalViewModel_CreditedParty_NotSpecified;

        return error;
    }

    private string ValidateDebitedParty()
    {
        string error = null;

        if (_debitNote.DebitedParty == _blankDebitedParty)
            error = Strings.JournalViewModel_DebitedParty_NotSpecified;

        return error;
    }

    #endregion
```

How does this code fire more than one validation? Can any one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event to trigger validation.

Comment: Validations are triggered in the same order as in which you fire PropertyChanged event on your ViewModel. For example, if you first fire PropertyChanged for property Amount, DependencyProperty that is data-bound to Amount property will be validated. Then if you fire PropertyChanged for property CreditedParty, DependencyProperty that is data-bound to CreditedParty property will be validated, etc..